# Запрет изменения переменной

Tags: javascript

Есть класс который должен быть инициализирован один раз. 
Как мне сделать так что бы при повторном создании "экземпляра класса" он не создался?

поставить в конструкторе if.

А вот что проверять? const не пойдет, так как его нужно объявлять только внутри класса.
записать созданный первый раз объект в window? Да, но ведь его можно будет удалить (window.obj) или изменить.

Как можно заморозить window.obj?

Comment: то что вы описываете называется синглтон, или паттерн (шаблон проектирования) "одиночка"

Comment: @teran это хорошо. но как мне решить проблему мою?

Comment: Добавь больше примеров кода. Что за класс? почему не просто литерал объекта? он сам по себе один раз делается. Зачем ты хочешь вызывать повторное создание?

Comment: _Да, но ведь его можно будет удалить (window.obj) или изменить._ - не всегда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать самоопределяемую функцию. После первого запуска она будет переопределена и при повторном вызове вернет объект, который был создан на этапе первого вызова.

```
var SomeClass = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.field1 = 'value1';
  /* ... */
  SomeClass = function() {
    return self;
  };
  return self;
};
```

Comment: а можно было просто вернуть нужный объект сразу